Problem Drawing JLabel as Column Header in JTable (and Overriding paintComponent)
I am trying to use a JLabel for column headers in a JTable, and override paintComponent to color a percentage of non-null values for each column, kind of like a background visualization of a fill rate. It seems to be quite straightforward, but for some reason visualization is always applied to the first (left) column only, like in the picture below:

The "fill rate" is just random in the example, but only applied for the first column although looping through all columns.
Edit: Using Java 8 and MacOS
The full source code is:
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CustomTable extends JFrame {

    private static class CustomLabel extends JLabel {

        public CustomLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int w = random.nextInt(getWidth());
            int h = getHeight();
            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(Color.green);
            g2.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
            super.paintComponent(g2);
            g2.dispose();
        }

    }

    private static class CustomTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            return ((CustomLabel) value);
        }

    }

    public CustomTable() {
        setTitle("CustomTable");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(320, 240);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        String[] columns = {"id", "fname", "lname"};
        String[][] data = {{"1", "John", "Doe"}, {"2", "Jane", "Doe"}};
        JTable jt = new JTable(data, columns);
        TableColumnModel model = jt.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel(columns[i]);
            model.getColumn(i).setHeaderValue(cl);
            model.getColumn(i).setHeaderRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());
        }
        add(new JScrollPane(jt));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                new CustomTable();
            }
        });
    }

}


int x = 0; guess why?

paintComponent is not just called when you want it to be called.  It can be called very frequently by Swing’s painting system.  You must not call any methods of Random in a painting method.  Update a variable outside of the paintComponent method, and then call a repaint method of the JTableHeader to let paintComponent make use of that variable.

Tried replacing the random part with a static value and calling repaint for all header values in the loop, but doesn't seem to do the trick. The paintComponent seems to be executed for all columns (e.g. the column names), just the graphics part for the first column.

Painting of a Swing component should always be done relative the to component, not the location of the component.
So custom painting should always have an x/y location of (0, 0), if you want to paint from the top/left of the component.
        int x = getX();
        int y = getY();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

Should be:
        //int x = getX();
        //int y = getY();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        //g2.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

Also, I assume you are just using the "random" method for the simplicity of the example code. As suggested above in the comment you should not be using random in a painting method since the paintComponent method is called every time a cell needs to be repainted. For example, resize the width of the frame to see the random results.

Of course, can't believe I didn't see this.
